# Stack Overflow's new profile doesn't know about Stack Overflow Careers existing profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, stack-overflow-jobs

I have a Stack Overflow profile linked to my Stack Overflow Careers profile.

Had them for a while now.

I have just been notified of the new Stack Exchange profile and went looking around.

Looks great, but in the "Web presence" section, the link to Stack Overflow Careers states I don't have an account and invites me to join (I'm in the *Edit profile* section).

[image: No SO Careers]

I'm signed in on both through Google.

Is this a bug, a feature yet to be implemented, or am I missing something out?

**Edit**

- Some bug tracking [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253459/166022) - thanks [Grant Winney](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/301857/grant-winney)
- Look at [Hunter McMillen](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/702638/hunter-mcmillen)'s comment for a workaround - thanks.

Comment: Go to the *edit profile* link; it'll ask you there if you want to make the link visible.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I **am** in the *Edit profile* section. I've just added a picture to illustrate better.

Comment: Ah, thanks for that clarification. I don't have an answer for that, I am afraid.

Comment: In your Careers profile, the *Stack Exchange* section lists your Stack Overflow profile, right?

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks for trying! And yes, my SO Careers profile is linked with SO, rep and answers etc. are visible.

Comment: Looks like there is a workaround: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253450/new-profile-pages-are-out-bugs-and-feedback-master-list/253471#253471

Comment: same here, so more people have this problem

Comment: thanks @HunterMcMillen, the workaround worked for me too

Comment: Thank you @HunterMcMillen. It seems to work for me too. At first the SO page complains a profile was found, "but hidden". A simple reload of the page fixes that. Feel free to answer if you deem it appropriate, I'll accept.

Comment: Please report issues and comments with the new profiles here on Meta Stack Exchange: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253450/new-profile-pages-are-out-bugs-and-feedback-master-list

Comment: @MichaelIrigoyen already in there, see comments and edit to my own question. I hadn't figured it out because it's not easy to look for. This question might actually lead more people to follow through your link ultimately. Also the workaround by HunterMcMillen solves the issue.

Comment: The workaround of toggling to private and back on the careers profile worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

This issue has been fixed, you should now have your Careers profile linked correctly.

Thanks for the report!

Comment: Uh, not quite? I still have the same issue, though I am not sure whether my profiles were linked before the new SO profile was introduced. That said I certainly can't link my careers profile to my SO profile, with the same symptoms as described by OP. The work around of making my careers profile public is not applicable as it already was and is public...